# mkdir system call occasionally creates unreadable directory

Tags: c, permissions, posix, mkdir

I'm taking in an ouput folder name as an argument with argv[] and then executing the following code:

```
mkdir(outputname, "0777");
```

And sometimes it will work fine and create the folder with the correct permissions but occasionally the folder will get created and I won't be able to access the folder. Is this a common problem problem with a simple fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sending a string to `mkdir` for the mode, and this is the wrong type. If you include the correct headers the compiler should warn you about this. The fix is simple enough,

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
...
mkdir(outputname, 0777);
```

Comment: `-Wall` is your friend :)